# How can I generate the same UUID for multiple dataframes in spark?

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a df that I read from a file

```
import uuid

df = spark.read.csv(path, sep="|", header=True)
```

Then I give it a UUID column

```
uuidUdf= udf(lambda : str(uuid.uuid4()),StringType())
df = df.withColumn("UUID",uuidUdf())
```

Now I create a view

```
view = df.createOrReplaceTempView("view")
```

Now I create two new dataframes that take data from the view, both dataframes will use the original UUID column.

```
df2 = spark.sql("select UUID from view")
df3 = spark.sql("select UUID from view")
```

All 3 dataframes will have different UUIDs, is there a way to keep them the same across each dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark uses a lazy evaluation mechanism, where the computation is invoked when you call `show` or other actions. This means every time you call an action,  the `uuid` is recalculated. To avoid this
you need to `cache` the `df` before you call `createOrReplaceTempView`, here is what you should do

```
import uuid

df = spark.read.csv(path, sep="|", header=True)
uuidUdf= udf(lambda : str(uuid.uuid4()),StringType())
df = df.withColumn("UUID",uuidUdf())

df.cache()

view = df.createOrReplaceTempView("view")

df2 = spark.sql("select UUID from view")
df3 = spark.sql("select UUID from view")
```

Comment: Depending on amount of data `.cache` not necessary will help.

Comment: Why?  What happens if I have alot of data?

Comment: @JS noob Probably what he means is that when data is too large to be held in memory,  `cache` won't help. But  I believe, without experiment, if the config for `cache` is set as `MEMORY_AND_DISK`,  Spark will cache data in memory and disk. So caching the data may still be helpful.